# Elastic v.7 - Painless script to filter by non indexed field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-painless

In some elastic documents, a field has been added that is not indexed in the mapping. I'm trying to filter for documents that don't have this field like this:

```
GET {index}/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": """
                          doc['published'].value == 'xxx'
                         """,
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried with `doc.containsKey('published')` inside souce;

However, as the field 'published' is not in the index mapping, I'm having the error:

"No field found for [published] in mapping with types []"

Is there a way to search/filter with this non-indexed field?

Here I found someone who did: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-search-non-indexed-field-in-elasticsearch/20594/4 . But that's an older elastic version and that query didn't work after adapting to the version 7.

Comment: What's the field definition for `published` in your mapping?

Comment: it's not in the mapping, that's the main issue. They don't want to change the mapping to insert; the field was added only in some documents.

Comment: Ok, but if it's in the documents, it means the [mapping is not dynamic then and not strict](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html) either. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, just checked the mapping and it has: `dynamic: false` .

Comment: it used to be possible to check directly in the `ctx._source` field within a script (even though it was slow), but it's not possible anymore, exactly for that reason.